# How to reduce power consumption in ubuntu?

Tags: 10.04, software-recommendation, power-management

Why does Ubuntu use more power than Windows? Which is the best **energy manager**?

Answer (score 3):

This [article](http://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/1610079/new-ubuntu-eats-power-windows) answers you about Ubuntu 10.04 needs more power.

There are many tools that you can use for reducing power consumption like:

1. [powertop](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/ReducedPower)

   ```
   sudo apt-get install powertop
   ```
2. [jupiter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jupiter/files/)

   Download and install the latest `*.deb` file. Launch it from the menu. It will create an applet in your tray, when you right click it, you will see what it does for you.
3. [MicroMiser](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/micromiser-power-saving-software-for-ubuntu-laptopsdesktopsservers.html)
4. From Ubuntu software center, search for `laptop-mode-tools` and install it.

Answer (score 1):

install gnome power manager

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-power-manager
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Jupiter. It works fine for me. You can grab it from PPA:

https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/jupiter

Comment: If this PPA will removed my answer will be completely unusable. Because my answer is "Try to install Jupiter".

Comment: ok just improve your answer then insert the link

Comment: @martini If the Jupiter PPA is removed, it will still be possible to install Jupiter, through other methods. In that circumstance, an answer explaining what Jupiter is and why you recommend it for this purpose would still be helpful. You might choose not to expand your answer further (and that's OK), but I still would consider maythux's advice to be good, and applicable to this situation.

Comment: @Eliah Kagan ok, ok. Answer was improved already after maythux's comment :) It was consisted of only link and no text before.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend visiting https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/PowerSavingTweaks and if you want to go further and identify power sucking apps also visit: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/IdentifyingIssues